# What are the storage and lodging capacities for the towns and cities in the game?

Tags: black-desert-online

I'm considering my options for a couple of towns to heavily invest contribution in. While I certainly have a slew of variables to consider, I'm trying to narrow things down a bit and a large consideration for me right now is lodging and storage space. What are the max lodging and storage capacity for the various towns in Black Desert Online? I'm only interested in large towns/cities. Random farms need not apply.

Comment: I can give you a great answer of how worker type and location should be "computed" if you choose to ask about it (with speed formulas etc, but answer is long and is not really related to the original question). Choosing investing by storage and lodging alone is not optimal.

Comment: @zozo That's not really a question that concerns me in particular because I'm not online enough to maximize the benefits of managing workers like that. But I'm sure someone somewhere on the internet would find it interesting.

Comment: say hello to Eilton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For storage, The largest city is Calpheon, this has the most building options, and is centrally located if you plan to stay on the "life side" of the map.

Another option, which most players seem to prefer, is Heidel. It is smaller than Calpheon (making it much easier to navigate), and still has plenty of options for building opportunities. Heidel is also more central to the entire map, making accessing every area a bit easier.

As for the lodging side of your question, you can have workers Live in Velia but still do work somewhere else entirely, it will just take a little bit longer. So again, Calpheon or Heidel will be your best option (there's no reason not to do both, it's cheaper contribution point investments that way anyway)

You can always permanently increase the storage/lodging units of cities with pearl/loyalty items as well.

Personally, I tend to stick around Calpheon more than Heidel, but that's because I do more work in Port Epheria nearby.

Comment: In regards to sending workers to any connected node regardless of where they are lodged, I agree. However, a factor there is that the worker will drop off what they produce in the city that are lodged in. One of my goals is to try to reduce how much traveling and/or shipping I have to do to centralize the assets being generated.

Comment: Then your best bet would be Calpheon, It has by far the most houses for storage and lodging, with many farm nodes nearby (the plantations) for workers. Velia also has great farm choices, but barely any space for buildings.

Answer (score 1):

All the inventories are limited at 192 slots. And all major cities can get to that.

Regarding lodging the largest you could get is from Calpheon, followed by Heidel, Altinova and Valencia (didn't count the exact the number but they looked rather similar to me), while Velia is totally worker deprived (for Balenos area you need to use workers from both Olvia and Velia to properly cover it).

As a side note thought (not requested by the question but I think is really important), you should consider the CP investment for what you need, and what nodes you want to send your workers to. Heidel is popular because Heidel lodging is really cheap (1 cp / lodging, even less for some). Valencia and Grana for example are really expensive. Also Heidel is near center of the map so you can cover more ground with it. There are more things to consider when choosing investing options.

Answer (score 0):

The four largest would be Veila, Heidel City, Calphaleon, and Altinova. If you are leveling quickly and hitting the desert soon, I recommend Altinova. If you are working on your life skills instead, any of the other three are fine.

Comment: So, this doesn't really answer my question. Of the towns you've listed, I'm asking what their max storage capacities are if I decide to commit the contribution points.